# How to convert SQL to SSIS task?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ssis

I execute a couple of SQL queries using a batch file. I want to execute all this SQL using SSIS also. Can someone suggest how I can do that?

Comment: BIDS --> Control flow --> Execute SQL Task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the basics of creating SSIS packages, I went to google and typed 'ssis for beginners':

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155829/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Part-1-Basics

You'll probably want to use one or more 'Execute SQL Task's. A guide to these can be found at:

http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/The-Execute-SQL-Task.aspx

You will probably want to use

> ConnectionType: OLE DB (or ADO.net)
>   Connection: Click here to setup a connection manager (should be a button towards the right of the text box)
>   ResultSet: Single Row
>   SQLSourceType: direct input
>   SQLStatement: You SQL command goes here

Don't worry too much about the other settings for now.

Comment: Thanks. I just needed to know what parts of the SSIS tool would be needed to solve my problem.

Comment: @sequel.learner You'll probably want to use one or more 'Execute SQL Task's. You will be able to create a connection manager beforehand or during your first setup of an execute SQL task.

Comment: @sequel.learner I've updated my answer with another link more specific to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wide open question. You can simply create a connection string and call the individual sqls or the stored procedure and be done with it. But that should not be the goal.

One advantage that an SSIS solution provides over the SQL statements that the task can be broken into smaller steps thus rendering your solution more structure and maintainability.